# Put docker container name in docker logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, filebeat

My overall problem is that I am using filebeat running on the host to push logs to ES/Kibana, and the name of the container is not a field (I do have container id).

How can I get the container name added to the details that are pushed to filebeat?

I attempted to add the container name to the logs by adding

```
logging:
  options:
    labels: ContainerName="{{.Name}}"
```

to my docker compose file, but that didn't see to do anything.

I am using the filebeat docker input type.

Any ideas for how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

record in docker-compose.yml

```
logging:
    driver: "json-file"
    options:
        tag: ContainerName="{{.Name}}"
```

will produce

```
{"attrs":{"tag":"ContainerName=\"your container name\""}}
```